# Importing csv file to SQL Server Management Studio and updating existing entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

I'm running SQL Server 2012 and have a database with about 20,000 entries.
I need to update a few columns for about 5,000 of them.

I have the columns in a csv and it basically looks like this:

```
ClientNumber    ClientName              TaxYear       OutputFileField
9455            James Bond and Company   2016          \local\cndps\93985.esx
```

I need to update the first 3 columns based on the 4th column match

So for instance I need to update the above to be

```
ClientNumber    ClientName              TaxYear       OutputFileField
1111            Luis Fandora            2044          \local\cndps\93985.esx
```

I tried importing thru SQL Server Management Studio, but that did not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can't you import the csv in a temporary table and update the original table with a join.

Comment: In what way did your attempt "not work"?   Did you get an error?   what was it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like @Shreyas Chavan suggested, you could do this:

- Create a temp table and load the new spreadsheet data.
- Next, join the existing table to your temp table on that 4th field (`OutputField`).
- Update your first three columns based on that join.

Here is a sample code:

```
CREATE TABLE #ClientInfo(
ClientNumber int NOT NULL,
ClientName nvarchar(255) NULL,
Tax_Year int NULL, 
OutputField nvarchar(255) NULL)
GO

BULK INSERT #ClientInfo
FROM 'C:\Documents and Settings\corewania\Desktop\ClientInfo.csv'    
       --change this to match your directory
WITH(  
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
GO


UPDATE oci
SET oci.ClientNumber = nci.ClientNumber,
    oci.ClientName = nci.ClientName,
    oci.Tax_Year = nci.Tax_Year 
FROM orig_Clientinfo oci
JOIN #ClientInfo nci on nci.OutputField = oci.OutputField;
```